# Centering img with CSS

Tags: css

Below is a simplification of my HTML code. I want to center img C within div A without taking element B into account. B has a background image with a width of 70px and C has a width of 300px. Width of div A is 50% of the screen.

```
<div id="A">
   <div id="B"></div><img id="C" src="x.png" />
</div>
```

I won't put my CSS code because at this point it seems as though I have tried every single possible combination of the display, margin, left properties. I'm stuck and getting frustrated. Help!

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B" onclick="something()" ></div>
    <img id="C" src="x.png" />
</div>
```

```css
#containsA {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
}

#A {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

#B {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url('some.png');
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#B:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('someOther.png');
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

#C {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 70px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ might help us in understanding your problem.

Comment: Why do you have two closing tags for div while only an opening one?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the source of the problem

Comment: Off-topic: It's better to use classes and ids in lowercase. Just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following technique allows to center an element while ignoring other elements. This way however, the element is taken out of the normal flow of elements, so, the container ignores it :

```css
#A {
    position: relative;
}
#C {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/p3XKW/.

Here is another suggestion. This time, I've chosen to take `#B` out of the flow in order to prevent the image from masking `#B` when the container is getting too small. Doing so, `#B` remains clickable but the container ignores its height. This might not be a problem if the height never varies :

```css
#A {
    position: relative;
}
#B {
    position: absolute;
}
#C {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/dzgLR/.

Comment: Second one did the trick; had to reload the page three times to make sure I wasn't hallucinating. Thank you so much procrastinator! You the man! Cat?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid, there is one closing `<div>` too much.
You could just use `text-align:center` on `#A` but that would affect `#B` also. So I'd go for this:

```
#A img
{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j93sM/

**Update:**

you use this CSS:

```
#B {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    background-image: url('some.png');
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

That makes hardly sense. If you use `float` the elements become `display: block;` by default. As i still don't really understand what you want, i'am guessing you the `<img>` to be over `#B`. You can do this, whith this CSS:

```
 #A img
 {
     display: block;
     margin: -70px auto auto auto;
 }
```

Also Remove this from `#C`

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: it's still taking B into account, what properties should B have?

Comment: @pownassis What do you mean by "without taking B into account"? Please include required clarifications directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry, it made sense in my head. I want C to be perfectly centered within A, but now it is offset by the space that B takes up. Is that clearer?

Comment: @pownassis post the actual html+css or this, or this makes no sense.

Comment: I start guessing now... If B is a background with a known height, you may do this: http://jsfiddle.net/j93sM/1/ but please post the code you used.

Comment: I added more code. My thing has 3 elements, yours has 2... maybe now it will be clearer, apologies

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is confusing, but based purely on abstract elements, this would work:

```
#a {
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This doesn't take element #b into account at all, and will center #c within #a, but I really don't know if it's what you want. Make sure and use prefixes as always.

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity. Um, your answer gives a wierd result. Everything has the same height so I don't want to modify the height in any way. Would that change your answer?

Comment: If you are purely centering horizontally, remove top: 50% and change the transform to transform: translateX(-50%);

Answer (score 0):

I don't why there is this `div#C`, any way try this. Hope this is the solution you need.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="A">
    <div id="B"></div>
    <img id="C" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#A
{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    border:3px solid red;
}

#B
{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/70/70/) no-repeat;
    border:3px solid blue;
    z-index:2;
}

#C
{
    z-index:1;
    border:3px solid green;
}

#B,#C
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ra29U/3/)**

Please note, I have used borders only for demo purpose to separate the elements.

Hope this helps.